# Why is only one rudder deflected on this Su 35?

Tags: aircraft-performance, military, flight-controls, flight-training

Why does the aircraft has only one rudder deflected in this picture?

[image]

Comment: Because the pilot is only stepping on the right rudder pedal.

Comment: @Michael -  Look closer. You can see the left rudder is deflected. It's just deflected outboard. They do this as a speed brake, not from rudder pedal depression. unlike Rutan canard aircraft, where each rudder pedal is independently hooked to only one rudder, and the rudders only deflect outboard, the rudder *pedals* in twin tailed fighters (like F-15, F-18, Mig-29, etc.), are mechanized the same way they are in a single tailed aircraft. The flight control computer actually controls the rudder surfaces, based on multiple inputs.

Comment: Even prior to "Fly-by-Wire" systems, as in the F-16. fighters often had integrated flight control systems that allowed the flight control surfaces to move based on more than one pilot control input. In early F-15s, for example, left-right deflection of the flight control stick caused both deflection of the ailerons, and differential stabilator, in varying degrees depending on the fore-aft position of the stick. When it was forward (implying Low AOA), the ailerons were deflected. As it moved aft, (higher AOA), less and less aileron, and more and more differential stabilator was generated.

Comment: Can you attribute the image correctly (i.e mention the source and photographer). See  also this [meta post](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501/19) for more info.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, I actually intended that comment as a joke.  But, your comments would make an excellent answer!

Comment: @Michael, my bad!  Add an exclamation point or a [\grin] or something to make it obvious...

Comment: Trimmed the image and edited to actually be a complete sentence with a question.

Answer (score 14):

[image]Both rudders are deflected, but from that angle you can't see the other one.  They are pointing outboard, as speed brakes.  (This image looks similar enough to some clips in a promotional [video](https://youtu.be/uga9W1oW7j0) by the Chinese Air Force, described by the [Xinhua News Agency](http://kr.xinhuanet.com/2018-05/14/c_137176826.htm), to suggest that that the photo was taken from a large Chinese military aircraft, thus by a member of the Chinese Air Force.  But I haven't found an exact attribution.)

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygQzrKCX4AI) of a scale model operating them simultaneously with the dorsal speed brake.

Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/9jmZaP1FeHM?t=315) of the rudders pointing outboard during approach and landing.
The Su-35S is piloted by Yuri Vashchuk,
at the [MAKS 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAKS_(air_show)) air show, Zhukovsky, Russia.
Filmed by Konstantin Khmelik.
[image]

Comment: Can you attribute the image correctly (i.e mention the source and photographer). See  also this [meta post](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501/19) for more info.